# Kafka auto commit interval best practice

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Are there any best practices when selecting value of auto.commit.interval.ms?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293622/kafka-how-to-commit-offset-after-every-message-using-high-level-consumer) that:

> In general, it is not recommended to keep this interval too small because it vastly increases the read/write rates in zookeeper and zookeeper gets slowed down because it's strongly consistent across its quorum.

What is too small? Is this still an issue with kafka >= 0.9.0 version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not *what is small*, but rather what can you live with? If you can live with re-processing several minutes of messages in case of a crash of your consumer, you could set the interval to a few minutes. Because this is what it is all about: messages will be processed after a (re)start from the last committed offset.