# Kafka consumer goes into an unending loop

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, infinite-loop

I am using Kafka queue to hold some objects that is to be retreived by consumer app and perform some operation on it.

Problem : If the processing by consumer takes more than ~2 hrs kafka seems to give back the same object again and again

Code :

```
  private static Queue queue = new LinkedList();
  while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n Kafka has :[" + record.offset());
                queue.add(record.value());
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n\n Kafka has :[" + records.count());
            if (queue != null) {
                maintainQueue();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using kafka version 0.10.1.0

We have resolved this issue
by updating 
`ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG  to "false"`
and adding `consumer.commitSync();` after `consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Reference :

> [Kafka - How to commit offset after every message using High-Level consumer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293622/kafka-how-to-commit-offset-after-every-message-using-high-level-consumer)
>
> http://www.slideshare.net/jjkoshy/offset-management-in-kafka